# When I drag any objects into autolayout in xcode, it automatically goes fullscreen and I can't resize it

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

Is there a setting I accidentally checked that would force this behavior? Even button objects occupy the entire screen.

Comment: I don't understand what this even means. Can you try to explain it better or at least show some screen shots or something?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I accidentally deleted the view object from the view controller. The view objects acts as a container for other objects and "handles the rendering of any content in its area and also handles any interactions with that content." You just drag and add the view object back in autolayout and everything works again.

Comment: Glad you got it working again :D I love it when I'm able to fix things myself. Sometimes all it takes is writing down the problem in StackOverflow and I will already think of a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

It's weird behaviour. Maybe fixed in new avaialble xCode. Anyways, after dragging an object, click on the object and goto Size Inspector and change the width and height along with X,Y if required. The size will be reduced and you can make use of it.

Answer (score -1):

For each object you have to reset the layout rules. Or disable the autolayout from your storyboard (look at the image)

[image]

Comment: Disabling AutoLayout will deny your app a ton of features introduced in iOS8 and iOS9. AutoLayout has been around for over 3 years. There is no excuse for not learning how to use it.

Comment: Depends... if you are working on a small storyboard this may help as temporary solution to restore the object size. If you read better, the option was set accidentally so probably is not a problem to remove the autolayout again. If you have a solution post the solution and not a down-vote please.

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to even make a solution yet. TBH there is no way that you could even know what the problem is. There is nothing about having AutoLayout checked that will cause views to disable resizing on them. Disabling AutoLayout is never the solution for anything like this. I'll post a solution when I know what the problem is. Until then the down vote will stay because a) you don't even know what the problem is and b) you recommended disabling auto layout.

Comment: I had a similar problem in past and I solved removing the auto layout , restored the size or position and after re-enabling the auto layout. For this reason I suppose my solution is the best until you provide your solution. If you didn't have this kind of problem, obviously you can't understand me. And I repeat: in the question, the auto layout was set accidentally. Because of this I suppose the user don't use auto-layout